# Is there is any way to create a backup of python virtual environment and restore it any linux distro?

Tags: python, backup

I am a fan of Linux. so always I switching into OSs in a few months. I am using also virtual box but I like physical installation them. As I am a developer I have to rebuild or reinstall my environment again when I installed a new OS. So I want to just take a backup of my python virtualenv and just put it in that new os. How can I do that?

Comment: Make a Docker image of it

Comment: Since your question isn't specifically about Ubuntu, you may want to submit it at our related site: [unix.se].

Comment: Generally you make a requirements.txt file and build your virtualenv from that.  We never copy them.  When testing its often better to test fresh anyway and delete the environment and install again.